# Configure sonarqube scanner to run as a step in cloud build on cloud source repository

Tags: sonarqube-scan, bitnami, google-cloud-build, sonarscanner

I've installed sonarqube bitnami instance and manually installed sonar-scanner looking for a way to trigger the scan from cloud build, Is there a way I can reference this sonarqube VM instance in my cloudbuild.yaml (Don't want to use docker)
Like for example using container its pulled like (gcr.io/project-id/sonar-scanner:latest) I want it to be pulled from that bitnami VM instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't be possible to use a VM instance to perform a build step. All steps that carried out on Cloud Build are performed using container images that are pulled and run on a single VM.

What you might be able to do is create an image that replicates as closely as possible the environment you have on that VM and include it as a [custom build step](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-custom-build-steps).

Comment: This means the bitnami sonarqube version then only useful inside the VM and there is no way around to use it into the my cloud build steps?